# Multiset declaration with comparator using function pointers

Tags: c++, constructor, function-pointers, multiset

This is an extension of the question asked and answered here: [How to define a multiset using a function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627530/how-to-define-a-multiset-using-a-function-pointer)

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to ask the user with the accepted answer my question as a comment (9 more to go ...), so here I am. Hopefully this was OK to do.

As in that question, I am also working through C++ Primer and am up to the same section. Using the simplified example given in the link above, I'm trying to understand this line:

`std::multiset<A, decltype(compareA)*> m1(compareA);`

As far as I am aware, this is the syntax for copy constructors. For example, initialising a multiset of integers `m1` as a copy of multiset `m2` is written as `std::multiset<int> m1(m2);`.

So what's going on here when we use function pointers? Is this just syntactic sugar to get the function pointer type returned by `decltype(compareA)*` to point to `compareA`? I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding what this line is doing.

As a side note, how am I meant to read the documentation on [std::multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) in order to answer this question? I feel like C++ documentation is much less accessible than, for instance, Java documentation, but perhaps I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `std::multiset<A, decltype(compareA)*> m1(compareA)` defines an object named `m1` of type `std::multiset<A, decltype(compareA)*>` and passes `compareA` as a parameter to its constructor.

`std::multiset`'s second template paramter is the *type* of comparator to use.  In this case, that's `decltype(compareA)*`: A pointer to the type of `compareA`.  Probably something like `bool (*)(const A&, const A&)`: Pointer to a function returning `bool` and accepting two `A` parameters by const reference.  That type by itself can't do any comparisons, you need an actual *object* of that type that points to a specific function.  Normally `std::multiset` will value-initialize an object of its comparator type, but for a function pointer type that would be a null pointer.  To deal with this,  `std::multiset` has [a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/multiset) (constructor (1) on that page) that accepts an object of its comparator type that it will use to do its comparisons.  Function names are implicitly convertible to a pointer to that function, so passing `compareA` is equivalent to `&compareA`.

Taking this all together, `m1`'s comparator type is "Pointer to a function accepting two `A`s".  You pass a pointer to `compareA` to its constructor, which it will then use to call `compareA` to do the comparisons it needs.

Comment: I feel very stupid having not clicked into the page leading to its constructors, and I can see the first constructor takes in a reference to a compare type with a default argument for the allocator parameter (whatever that is). Everything makes sense now. Thank you for your answer! :)